# Insert record into table using default values and values selected from another table using where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it is possible to insert records into a table by using a select statement on a different table, but I need to use a where clause to select which record. For example,

```
INSERT INTO Employee_Archive(EmployeeID, Name, ArchiveReason)
SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employees, Name from Employees, 'Retired'
WHERE EmployeeID = '001'
```

I hope that example makes sense. I wish to get the EmployeeID and the Name from the Employees table, and add my own ArchiveReason value, but I need to specify by which EmployeeID. Cheers

Comment: `SELECT EmployeeID, Name, 'Retired' FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = '001'`

Comment: @FelixPamittan..you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, 
    Name,
    'Retired' 
FROM Employees 
WHERE EmployeeID = '001'
```